# Is generating a python class considered wasteful with regard to resources?

Tags: python, resources

When considering a creation of a class in python just for having some attributes defined, as far as i understand, one should consider using a better data type like namedtuple which is considered more efficient.

my question - is it true that in such cases its better using namedtuple or maybe a dict ? is it true that a python class wont be efficient solution in such a case ? and general speaking , when should i avoid creating a new class and choose another data type ?

thanks
Sivan

Answer (score 0):

When you create a class in python, you create a namespace for each instance which contains its attributes. It depends on where you declare your tuple, but it is a little less efficient to access variable in a "larger" namespace than in a more "closer" namespace. For example:

```
toto = [1, 2, 3]
class Toto():
    def __init__(self):
        self.tup = [1, 2, 3]
print(toto)
toto_inst = Toto()
print(toto_inst.tup)
```

It should cost more to do the first print than the second because toto is in the more global namespace and in toto_inst.tup, Python knows exactly where it is in memory, but it have to look in which namespace, looking for more and more global namespace, where the toto variable is. But in 75% of cases the cost is insignificant.

But creating the instances has a cost too, so it is complicated. If it is just a simple tuple you should just use a variable not a class containing it. If you have much more attributes, and namespace, you should choose the way to make python have a nice life by looking directly at the corresponding namespace

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not considered wasteful to define a class.  By far the most important consideration in 99.9% of programs is clarity of the code.  Write the code that best expresses your idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a small difference between a standard class and a python dict.

```
import os
import psutil

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f, g):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        self.e = e
        self.f = f
        self.g = g

foos = [Foo(*range(7)) for _ in xrange(10000)]

process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print process.memory_info().rss
```

output ~15286000

```
import os
import psutil

foos = [{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'g': 6} for _ in xrange(10000)]

process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print process.memory_info().rss
```

output ~14890000

So a dict seems lighter

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you should not reinvent the wheel, ever. However, it is perfectly reasonable to define a class that suits your needs. And remember, [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: I like the wiki record :)